# HC-05 3.3 voltage regulation

Tags: voltage

HC-05 Bluetooth RX requires 3.3 v (TX has a regulator built in) 
I understand my uno and nano are 5v
Ive connected a 3.3v Zennor in series with a led and resistor and with multimeter established the black stripe goes ground to achieve 3v 
But which is considered ground between hc-05 RX or the arduino TX that it connects to.. 
Is this an acceptable way to drop the voltage? 
If not I've ordered some small voltage regulators. 
But I still have the same question, which way round. 
The regulator has connections v1...gnd...vo
Thanks Paul
(Edit to this post)
Ive read a bit more and if correct I now think the Hc-05 rx connects direct with the arduino tx and the Zennor connect anode to the link and stripe side to ground...
Still unsure..

Comment: All you need are two resistors. As shown in every single tutorial for using the HC-05 with an Arduino.

Comment: Thanks... Where are thease tutorials? . I've watched 12 now on YouTube and they are all connecting them direct. One guy at the start mentioned he was going to use two resistors then proceeded not to use any in his video..

Comment: YouTube is worse than instructables for being full of crap. Type "hc-05 Arduino" into Google and look at the pictures.